# Online Internet Explorer Simulators

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-6, internet-explorer-7, cross-browser

(Tried to find simular questions / duplicates, failed)

I develop on a mac. I love my mac. I develop using Chrome, Firefox, and Safari. I love them all for different reasons.

But I have to develop for Internet Explorer users as well.

I know, I am not unique here.

I enjoy using the webkit inspector / firebug to mess with CSS. One of the biggest issues I've found when testing ie6-8 is the inability to edit CSS on the fly. The back and forth to a VM or an actual pc, trying something in CSS, saving, reloading in IE, failing, and repeating, leads to a slow development process.

So, on to my actual question.

Is there any sort of online emulator/simulator for various internet explorer versions? Something that somehow renders the page using the ie engine, but still allows me to use my inspector?

Is this even possible?

Comment: see this article (from 2011) http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/09/02/reliable-cross-browser-testing-part-1-internet-explorer/

Comment: But now (2013) you have [www.spoon.net](http://www.spoon.net) and [www.browserstack.com](http://www.browserstack.com)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could try [Firebug Lite](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite)

It's a pure JavaScript-implementation of Firebug that runs directly in any browser (at least in all major ones: IE6+, Firefox, Opera, Safari and Chrome)

You'll still need the VM to actually run IE, but at least you'll get a quicker testing cycle.

Comment: Definitely a step closer

Answer (score 36):

Have you tried this: [IE NetRenderer](https://netrenderer.com/)

Comment: Works only for Windows...doesn't it?

Comment: Nope, I'm using it on a mac. It creates a screen shot of how it would look in ie.

Comment: Something like alkaline litmus... a webkit-like API-based App would be tremendously useful though...

Comment: This is a website and works of course everywhere.

Answer (score 36):

Here is another idea for you. It is also online w/ no download. It uses window 7 + ie9 with no flash support though [ie9 online](http://cloudinternetexplorer.com/)

Comment: Very solid, good for testing/tweaking end-user experience. No access to the more advanced features (debugger/view source/...) of internet explorer but it does offer an interactive experience without any hassle of registration or plugins.

Answer (score 20):

http://www.browserstack.com

It really works great, but you only have 30 minutes/month for free.

For 19$/month you have unlimited time.

Comment: Is it 30 minutes/month for free or a single 30 minute trial?

Comment: Each month you have 30 minutes for free

Comment: Now they use a trial period.. :(  But awesome no less!

Comment: I can't believe that they try to charge so much for that. $19 was reasonable but not $39+ a month!

Comment: The $19 plan is a written in small text but it's still available.

Comment: @RugerSR9, the $19/mo is desktop browsers only, $39 is mobile and desktops. 

I've just used my trial for work, this tool is exactly what i needed.

Answer (score 6):

Something like [BrowserShots](http://browsershots.org/)?

Comment: No, not just a screenshot. I want to be able to interact with the site. I want to be able to right click an element, inspect it, edit the css, etc.

Comment: @hookedonwinter: Ah, in that case I don't think any online tool is going to suit you, since it'll always be at least abstracted behind your own browser and therefore not a good test.  VMs will probably be your most accurate approach for testing.  The tools won't be as good across the board, but unless you're actually using the target browser then you're not really testing for the target browser.

Comment: that's what I'm afraid of. Hopefully someone will know of some random awesomeness that will benefit us all. Like jsfiddle for ie or something sweet like that.

Answer (score 4):

I just realized that there's yet another option. I've heard a lot of good things about this service: [Litmus Alkaline](http://litmusapp.com/alkaline).

"Alkaline tests your website designs across 17 different Windows browsers right from your Mac desktop in seconds. No need for virtual machines, Windows licenses, or any messing around with Windows Update."

Comment: I've not used it myself (yet) but it appears to be screenshots only, so it might not be a relevant answer. Still, someone else might find this solution useful.

Comment: Just installed it. It is screenshots only, but it's still pretty slick. Doesn't really help with any ajax content, but ya.. pretty cool

Answer (score 2):

I've been using IE Tester (good) but didn't know I could simply switch versions in IE.  It's nice to know the browser voted "Most likely to be the bain of your existence" has the tool built in to look at previous versions.

The down side to IE Tester is it does not support javascript well, and also doesn't always do a great job with iframes.  (Yes, I still use them.)

I decided that since Google and Facebook no longer support IE7, I won't either.  I have a lot less funding than they do.

I know this doesn't fix the need to use VM for MAC users, but there should be ways around that too.  With an 8 core processor PC computer, you can VM MAC with 4 cores, same for PC, and run 4 displays, two for each OS.  Expensive, but this is our business.  In most business models, it is not uncommon to spend tens of thousands of dollars on equipment.  We shouldn't think of ourselves any differently.  Invest in your success.

Comment: Please don't attempt to reply to another answer by posting your own answer. That is not how this site works.

Answer (score 2):

Use wine - it has IE6 with Gecko support built into it.
More information [here](http://www.winehq.org/).

Answer (score 1):

If you have enough space on your hard-disk in your OS-X of Apple, then you could
install virtualbox for Mac-OS-X after download
at http://virtualbox.org

Then you would need "only" 100 GB to create with this virtualbox as virtual harddisk.
Then install for intentions of tests simply for 1 month-free-testtime a Windows of your choice - Vista or 7 or 8 - together with internet explorer ...

You dont need to buy Windows for this as long as you dont test longer than one month - when testing time is expired it is not tragic at all, you simply can repeat a new testing-time ...

This looks trivial but with virtualbox you have a real-time-testing-area in this case with IE - no matter which version of IE !

Answer (score 0):

[Adobe Contribute](http://www.adobe.com/products/contribute/) provides a snapshot service also, but it's not free.

Here's the [developer toolbar for IE 6 and 7](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=e59c3964-672d-4511-bb3e-2d5e1db91038&displaylang=en).

Comment: You can use the Dev Toolbar to edit CSS on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

By way of reference, here is another screenshot rendering tool: https://browserlab.adobe.com/

It also does a number of other browsers and platforms as well, and provides a few nice little options like onion skinning etc.

---

*Note: It seems that recently Internet Explorer 6 was removed, which makes it considerably less useful :S*

Answer (score -2):

Just stick with the virtual machine:
If you're running Internet Explorer 8 you'll be able to activate the developer window using F12. There you're able to edit CSS as well as HTML on the fly without saving/reloading the page.

Comment: That's my current solution, but the dev window is abysmal when compared to firebug or something similar.