# IE 8 Testing With Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I am debugging a design which is too messy on IE 8 to IE 10. Its looks great on Chrome, Safari, Opera and Firefox.

The problem i am having is i am easy with Chrome inspect elements and IE 8 developers tools are headache. I am trying to solve problem from last 2 days but no luck becuase IE Developer tools sucks.

I tried using different tools like, BrowseremAll and BrowserStack.

I am wondering if there is any way to use chrome inspect elements in IE 8 OR there is any Good IE simulator for Chrome?

Please advice!

Answer (score 3):

Here is the list of Apps that can help you test IE in Chrome:

- [**Chrome Web Store  - Test IE**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/test-ie/eldlkpeoddgbmpjlnpfblfpgodnojfjl?hl=en)
- [**Chrome Web Store - IE Tab**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ie-tab/hehijbfgiekmjfkfjpbkbammjbdenadd?hl=en)
- [**IE Tab for Chrome and Firefox**](http://www.ietab.net/)

More Options are Discussed Here:

**[Online Internet Explorer Simulators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426498/online-internet-explorer-simulators)**

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

in explorer10, may be in 11 too, you can use the browser mode selector present in developer tools, to make your ie behave like some old version ie. then you can test the website.

[image]

if you want to use chrome only strictly for testing, have a look at **IE Tab** chrome extension

```
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ie-tab/hehijbfgiekmjfkfjpbkbammjbdenadd
```

also, Microsoft offers a bunch of virtual machines images for all their browser versions on different OS versions. You might be able to install Chrome frame addon into the IE version you want to test.

```
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11575
```

also, spoon and browsershots that lets us to see our webpage in IE

Comment: For your first advice, Yes there is a option in IE 11 to switch browsers but its not that real. I used it on my Windows 8 machice and it shows website great!! and when i downgrade IE to IE 8 then it shows how messy it looks, so thumbs down for it. and i tested IE Tab it doesn't show any developers tools. also Browser snap will not work becuase i can"t debug code in a SNAP!!!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider using IE and [DebugBar](http://www.debugbar.com/download.php)

It's not perfect, but it can be a bit better than the IE developer tools.